# .NET WebView2 OLE class name

Tags: vsto, activex, ole, webview2

I was wondering if it's possible to use WebView2 in a VSTO PowerPoint add-in, by adding it on a slide using [Shapes.AddOLEObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff762425(v=office.12)) Interop function. Shapes.AddOLEObject requires the ClassName of the inserted object and can't figure out if Webview2 expose this by default.
I managed to add it to a WPF form, shown during PowerPoint slideshow. Now I need to add the WebView2 browser directly into a slide.
Creating an ActiveX control in .NET C# (a user control with a WebView2 object on it) and exposing that to PowerPoint would work?

The planned development environment is C# .NET framework 4.7.2 and latest PowerPoint version.

Comment: WebView2 doesn't have ActiveX support in its COM/Win32 API. WebView2 does have a .NET API including controls for WinForms (Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2) and WPF (Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.WebView2). I'm not familiar with VSTO PowerPoint add-ins so I don't know if that helps or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop an ActiveX control using WebView2, see [Get started with WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/win32) for more information.

The [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.864.35) control (`Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2`) is effectively a wrapper around the `WebView2` COM API. You can directly access the underlying `ICoreWebView2` interface and all of its functionality by accessing the `CoreWebView2` property. Some of the most common COM functionality is also accessible directly through wrapper methods/properties/events on the control.